# Different AES-256 encryption output between mbedtls and openssl

Tags: encryption, openssl, mbedtls

I'm working on an application that needs to decrypt a file by mbedtls which is encrypted by openssl. Currently, the decryption is not working. After investigation I've found that I cannot create the same encrypted file by using the two frameworks. What is the difference between the two encryption approaches?

Openssl:

```
 ->  ✗ cat message 
      hello world

 ->   ✗ openssl aes-256-ecb -nosalt -K 6261757363680000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 -in message -out koekoek.bin

 ->   ✗ xxd koekoek.bin
      00000000: 68e1 1f1e 8397 a33e ddea 5c4d 3192 11ab  h......>..\M1...
```

MbedTLS:

```
(gdb) p (void)memset(decrypt_output, 0, 16)
$63 = void
(gdb) p sprintf(decrypt_output, "hello world")
$64 = 11
(gdb) p/x key
$65 = {0x62, 0x61, 0x75, 0x73, 0x63, 0x68, 0x0 <repeats 26 times>}
(gdb) p mbedtls_aes_setkey_enc(&aes, key, 256)
$66 = 0
(gdb) p mbedtls_aes_crypt_ecb(&aes, MBEDTLS_AES_ENCRYPT, decrypt_output, decrypt_output) 
$67 = 0
(gdb) p/x decrypt_output 
$68 = {0x1b, 0x7c, 0x4d, 0x41, 0xaf, 0xa4, 0x65, 0x7f, 0x56, 0x39, 0x95, 0x2a, 0x21, 0x32, 0x10, 0xab}
(gdb)
```

Comment: The data (file) you encrypted in `openssl` contained the characters `h e l l o sp w o r l d` AND A **NEWLINE, PLUS** by default `openssl enc` adds PKCS5/7 **PADDING** to the block boundary (in this case 4 bytes containing 04). You need to make the data _exactly_ the same. PS: for a key like this you can say `openssl enc -K 626175636368` and it zero-pads; OTOH you shouldn't be using a very-low-entropy key like this in the first place.

Comment: Not very explicit in Dave's comment, but `mbed_tls` doesn't pad by default, while `openssl` CLI does use PKCS#7 compatible padding by default. So you'll have to perform the padding in `mbed_tls`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following `openssl` command produces the same result as your mbedtls script:

```
echo -ne "hello world\0\0\0\0\0" | openssl aes-256-ecb -nopad -K 6261757363680000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 | xxd -p
```

produces:

```
1b7c4d41afa4657f5639952a213210ab
```

Note that the input string is padded up to 16 characters in length (i.e. the length of one AES block) using null (`\0`) characters, to match what mbedtls does by default (the `-e` option is needed with `echo` to allow null characters in the input).  Also, the `-n` option is used with `echo` so that `echo` does not append a newline character to the input.  Finally, the `-nopad` option is used with the `openssl` command, so that `openssl` does not add an additional block of pkcs#7 padding.